# Is there a way to show "italic, "bold", "underline" buttons on Android keyboard?

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, android-jetpack-compose, android-textinputedittext

I am working on an Android app in compose,
When writing text, I need to show a keaybord that has the "underline", "italic" and "bold" buttons present on top of the keyboard text.
Is there a way I can do that?

Currently, this is what I have:

```kotlin
val keyboardController = LocalSoftwareKeyboardController.current
var textValue by remember { mutableStateOf(TextFieldValue("Write your text...")) }
TextField(
    value = textValue,
    modifier = Modifier
        .padding(16.dp)
        .fillMaxWidth(),
    placeholder = { Text(text = "John Doe") },

     textStyle = TextStyle(
        color = Color.Gray,
        fontSize = 20.sp,
      //  fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
      //  textDecoration = TextDecoration.Underline
    ),

    // Update value of textValue with the latest value of the text field
    onValueChange = {
        textValue = it
    },

    keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(imeAction = ImeAction.Done),
    keyboardActions = KeyboardActions(
        onDone = {
            keyboardController?.hide()
            // do something here
        }
    )    )
```

Comment: I believe there isn't any inbuilt solution to this. You may have to make your own `Composable` or `View` for that.

Comment: @OmKumar do you have any idea how to search for a solution or some help here? Thx

Comment: Try making a Composable, Row of Buttons and place it to parent content's bottom. Show / hide it using onFocusChanged modifier on TextField.